# How to interpret a three dimensional dataset?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I loaded a MATLAB dataset into python (using mat4py). It's shape is

```
(513L, 1L, 40L)
```

What does this mean?

Thanks

Comment: What were the dimensions before? The 2nd dimension is length one, so it might not contain meaningful data and just be an artifact of wrong conversion of a 2D (513 x 40) dataset.

Comment: when I loaded the dataset in MATLAB, it has two components

T: 513x1 cell
X: 48x1 cell

Comment: See also: [`scipy.io.load_mat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html#scipy.io.loadmat)

Comment: can't, it causes python to crash. That's apparently a bug in the newest scipy update.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

Consider the following

```
import numpy as np

print np.random.rand(10).shape

(10,)
```

The shape is 10 elements in a one-dimensional vector.

However:

```
print np.random.rand(10, 1).shape

(10, 1)
```

The shape signifies a 10 row, 1 column matrix.

The difference is subtle.  Mathematically, they are equivalent.  Programatically, they behave differently.

You're question: how to interpret `(513L, 1L, 40L)`

This looks like a 513x40 matrix given a 3rd dimension presence making it suitable for tensor manipulation.

Comment: thanks. I opened the dataset in matlab. It had cells, Then i converted those to a 2D array and then imported it in Python, lol